# Name for categories in which isomorphic implies equal?

Tags: category-theory, terminology

A quick terminology question: Is there any particular name for a category in which each object is uniquely determined by its isomorphism class?

Comment: This is not exactly what you want (in the sense that it refers to a full isomorphism dense subcategory with this property), but is close: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeleton_%28category_theory%29

Comment: Actually, the answer is in the article. They're called "skeletal". If you want some math points, post your response as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This article describes "skeletal" categories, which have the property you desire: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeleton_%28category_theory%29

Answer (score 0):

A "gaunt" category is similar, but does not allow any nontrivial automorphisms, which are allowed in a skeletal category. http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/gaunt+category

Comment: I ran across this terminology long after I posted the question and accepted the answer.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks for pointing that out. I edited the answer.